# Gapps script: using user auth credentials to authorize vs external django app service (which uses google as oauth provider)

Tags: django, google-apps-script

The workflow I need:

- User authenticated via google to a **g-apps** spreadsheet with google-apps-script.
- The script then calls an external service( a django app) which uses oauth for login with google backend - and authenticates with the user google credentials.

Searched from the [G-apps api docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) but couldn't find how to utlizlize the use existing google login to authenticate vs an external service also using google oauth login (there are docs to connecting to a google api, but that's a different use case)

Is this even possible? if so - How can I access the user credentials directly or preferably allow [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) to use the credentials transparently.

Maybe my google foo is failing me, but I can't find examples/explanations for this scenario.

Comment: C'mon mate... you've been around on Stack Overflow long enough to know that this is off topic because it's too broad.

Comment: @solarissmoke I've edited trying to limit the scope,